# Converting NSData to SecKeyRef

Tags: ios, encryption, rsa, nsdata, public-key-encryption

i have a public key which i gathered from a remote server and i want to perform RSA encryption with that public key. But the problem is i get the public key data as byte array in buffer. I can convert it to NSData but i can not convert to SecKeyRef so i can keep going with encryption. My encryption code is like:

```
+(NSString *)encryptRSA:(NSString *)plainTextString withKey:(SecKeyRef)publicKey {
size_t cipherBufferSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(publicKey);
uint8_t *cipherBuffer = malloc(cipherBufferSize);
uint8_t *nonce = (uint8_t *)[plainTextString UTF8String];
SecKeyEncrypt(publicKey,
              kSecPaddingOAEP,
              nonce,
              strlen( (char*)nonce ),
              &cipherBuffer[0],
              &cipherBufferSize);
NSData *encryptedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:cipherBuffer length:cipherBufferSize];
return [encryptedData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
```

}

As you can see i need SecKeyRef object type to complete my encryption. But my RSA public key is in NSData variable. So how can i convert NSData to SecKeyRef object type. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this function to save your public key. Pass your RAS public key and any name for peername.

```
- (void)addPeerPublicKey:(NSString *)peerName keyBits:(NSData *)publicKeyData {

        OSStatus sanityCheck = noErr;
        CFTypeRef persistPeer = NULL;
        [self removePeerPublicKey:peerName];

        NSData * peerTag = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:(const void *)[peerName UTF8String] length:[peerName length]];
        NSMutableDictionary * peerPublicKeyAttr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [peerPublicKeyAttr setObject:(id)kSecClassKey forKey:(id)kSecClass];
        [peerPublicKeyAttr setObject:(id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(id)kSecAttrKeyType];
        [peerPublicKeyAttr setObject:peerTag forKey:(id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
        [peerPublicKeyAttr setObject:publicKeyData forKey:(id)kSecValueData];
        [peerPublicKeyAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(id)kSecReturnData];
        sanityCheck = SecItemAdd((CFDictionaryRef) peerPublicKeyAttr, (CFTypeRef *)&persistPeer);

        if(sanityCheck == errSecDuplicateItem){
            TRC_DBG(@"Problem adding the peer public key to the keychain, OSStatus == %ld.", sanityCheck );
        }

        TRC_DBG(@"SecItemAdd OSStATUS = %ld", sanityCheck);

//        TRC_DBG(@"PersistPeer privatekey data after import into keychain %@", persistPeer);
        persistPeer = NULL;
        [peerPublicKeyAttr removeObjectForKey:(id)kSecValueData];
        sanityCheck = SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef) peerPublicKeyAttr, (CFTypeRef*)&persistPeer);

        TRC_DBG(@"SecItemCopying OSStATUS = %ld", sanityCheck);
//        TRC_DBG(@"SecItem copy matching returned this public key data %@", persistPeer);
        // The nice thing about persistent references is that you can write their value out to disk and
        // then use them later. I don't do that here but it certainly can make sense for other situations
        // where you don't want to have to keep building up dictionaries of attributes to get a reference.
        //
        // Also take a look at SecKeyWrapper's methods (CFTypeRef)getPersistentKeyRefWithKeyRef:(SecKeyRef)key
        // & (SecKeyRef)getKeyRefWithPersistentKeyRef:(CFTypeRef)persistentRef.
        [peerTag release];
        [peerPublicKeyAttr release];
        if (persistPeer) CFRelease(persistPeer);
    }
```

This is the function to retrieve the public key ref. Pass the same name which one is used for save.

```
-(SecKeyRef)getPublicKeyReference:(NSString*)peerName{

       OSStatus sanityCheck = noErr;

       SecKeyRef pubKeyRefData = NULL;
       NSData * peerTag = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:(const void *)[peerName UTF8String] length:[peerName length]];
       NSMutableDictionary * peerPublicKeyAttr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

       [peerPublicKeyAttr setObject:(id)kSecClassKey forKey:(id)kSecClass];
       [peerPublicKeyAttr setObject:(id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(id)kSecAttrKeyType];
       [peerPublicKeyAttr setObject:peerTag forKey:(id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
       [peerPublicKeyAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:       (id)kSecReturnRef];
       sanityCheck = SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef) peerPublicKeyAttr, (CFTypeRef*)&pubKeyRefData);
       [peerTag release];
       [peerPublicKeyAttr release];

       TRC_DBG(@"SecItemCopying OSStATUS = %ld", sanityCheck);
       if(pubKeyRefData){
           TRC_DBG(@"SecItem copy matching returned this publickeyref  %@", pubKeyRefData);
           return pubKeyRefData;
       }else{
           TRC_DBG(@"pubKeyRef is NULL");
           return nil;
       }
   }
```

Pass your public key data to this function before addPeerPublicKey

```
- (NSData *)stripPublicKeyHeader:(NSData *)d_key
{
    // Skip ASN.1 public key header
    if (d_key == nil) return(nil);

    unsigned int len = [d_key length];
    if (!len) return(nil);

    unsigned char *c_key = (unsigned char *)[d_key bytes];
    unsigned int  idx    = 0;

    if (c_key[idx++] != 0x30) return(nil);

    if (c_key[idx] > 0x80) idx += c_key[idx] - 0x80 + 1;
    else idx++;

    // PKCS #1 rsaEncryption szOID_RSA_RSA
    static unsigned char seqiod[] =
    { 0x30,   0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86, 0xf7, 0x0d, 0x01, 0x01,
        0x01, 0x05, 0x00 };
    if (memcmp(&c_key[idx], seqiod, 15)) return(nil);

    idx += 15;

    if (c_key[idx++] != 0x03) return(nil);

    if (c_key[idx] > 0x80) idx += c_key[idx] - 0x80 + 1;
    else idx++;

    if (c_key[idx++] != '\0') return(nil);

    // Now make a new NSData from this buffer
    return([NSData dataWithBytes:&c_key[idx] length:len - idx]);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this function returns nil and i examine the code peerKeyRef variable been initializing with NULL and after doing nothing with this variable function returns it, so it is NULL.

Comment: Sorry M. Salih Kocak...The first method just store the public key key (NSData). Second method returns your public seckeyref. Please try this.

Comment: Hi, i wrote like that but still i get public key as null:`NSData* publicKeyData = [[NSData alloc]initWithBytes:publicKeyBuffer length:publicKeyLen];
    [self addPeerPublicKey:@"PeerName" keyBits:publicKeyData];
    SecKeyRef publicKey = [self getPublicKeyReference:@"PeerName"];`

Comment: I checked publicKeyBuffer with debug mode it has right value there is no problem with that, also there is no problem with publicKeyData. What am i doing wrong i can not understand. Thanks again.

Comment: I suspect that if your public key is not generated by ios then you should to some conversion before store public key then only you can get SecKeyRef. I think this will solve your problem please refer the code I have added

Comment: Tons of thanks jai!!!! Now it works and i can get my public key reference. You were right just because public key doesnt created at iOS side there are some troubles with scheme. So again thank you so much. :)

Comment: now i encountered a problem which is when i send the rsa encrypted message from iOS to server, server cannot decrypt the message probably caused by `stripPublicKeyHeader` function. This method provide me to recognize the public key by iOS but when i encrypt the string with stripped public key, server can not decrypt it. You have any idea about where is the problem might be? You think after decryption we must add something to decrypted data in order to recognized by server? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Hi can you add the function to get which you are using to get nsdata from SecKeyRef publickey?

Answer (score 0):

Hope It will work....

```
-(NSData*)convertIOSKeyToASNFormat:(NSData*)iosKey{

    static const unsigned char _encodedRSAEncryptionOID[15] = {
        /* Sequence of length 0xd made up of OID followed by NULL */
        0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86,
        0xf7, 0x0d, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00
    };

    // OK - that gives us the "BITSTRING component of a full DER
    // encoded RSA public key - we now need to build the rest

    unsigned char builder[15];
    NSMutableData * encKey = [[[NSMutableData alloc] init] autorelease];
    int bitstringEncLength;

    // When we get to the bitstring - how will we encode it?
    if  ([iosKey length ] + 1  < 128 )
        bitstringEncLength = 1 ;
    else
        bitstringEncLength = (([iosKey length ] +1 ) / 256 ) + 2 ;

    // Overall we have a sequence of a certain length
    builder[0] = 0x30;    // ASN.1 encoding representing a SEQUENCE

    // Build up overall size made up of -
    size_t i = sizeof(_encodedRSAEncryptionOID) + 2 + bitstringEncLength +
    [iosKey length];

    size_t j = [self encodeLen:&builder[1] length:i];
    [encKey appendBytes:builder length:j +1];

    // First part of the sequence is the OID
    [encKey appendBytes:_encodedRSAEncryptionOID
                 length:sizeof(_encodedRSAEncryptionOID)];

    // Now add the bitstring
    builder[0] = 0x03;
    j = [self encodeLen:&builder[1] length:[iosKey length] + 1];

    builder[j+1] = 0x00;
    [encKey appendBytes:builder length:j + 2];

    // Now the actual key
    [encKey appendData:iosKey];
    return encKey;
}
```

Comment: @jailani: Here, encodeLen:length: function is missing. Can you please update the dependent functions as well?