# Difference between SecKeyCreateEncryptedData and SecKeyEncrypt in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, swift3, enclave

When trying to encrypt a block of plain data using SecKeyCreateEncryptedData, it encrypts the plain data using the specified algorithm and it works fine.The code snippet which i used for encryption is

```
SecKeyCreateEncryptedData(publicKey.underlying,SecKeyAlgorithm.eciesEncryptionSt
    andardX963SHA1AESGCM,cdata!, &error)
```

But when i am trying to do the same encryption using SecKeyEncrypt, it fails with a return value of (-50).The code snippet used for my encryption is

```
SecKeyEncrypt(publicKey.underlying as SecKey, .PKCS1, digestBytes, 
    newdata.length, &signatureBytes, &signatureLength)
```

And I am also unable to get the error description for the error code -50.

Comment: Learn about from here:- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1617956-seckeyencrypt

Comment: Is there a way to get the error description from the return value of SecKeyEncrypt. SecCopyErrorMessageString is not providing me the error description.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general difference between these two functions, not only limited to Swift.

`SecKeyCreateEncryptedData` function is intended for replacing the usage of `SecKeyEncrypt` since it is only available for iOS 10+, and Apple official guide is using that. Although both function takes `SecKey` as a parameter, the way to get the instance is also different.

If you `publicKey` is working fine for `SecKeyCreateEncryptedData`, chances are that the same `publicKey` won't work for `SecKeyEncrypt` function.

To correctly generate the `SecKey` for `SecKeyEncrypt` function, you need to

1. Get the `SecCertificate` by using `SecCertificateCreateWithData`. Note that the certificate should be in `.der` format.
2. Create and evaluate a `SecTrust` based on the `SecCertificate` you just created.
3. Get the `SecKey` from the `SecTrust`

You can find more details here [How can I get SecKeyRef from DER/PEM file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579985/how-can-i-get-seckeyref-from-der-pem-file).